# C++ gives random value when combining chars

Tags: c++

I have a string `039` and i have this following code

```
cout<<str2[1]+str2[0]+str2[2]<<endl;
```

I expect this to give me `309`,but it gives me `156`.How is that considering that separately all they give me  `3 0 9`?

Comment: Try this: `cout<<str2[1]<<str2[0]<<str2[2]<<endl;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are summing the characters / their underlying integral values together. If you want to output the characters themselves use the `<<` operator, not the `+`. The characters and their underlying values are (assuming ASCII):

```
'3'    51  
'0'    48  
'9'    57
```

The expression of:

```
str2[1] + str2[0] + str2[2]
```

sums the characters together, it does not send them to standard output one by one, so the expression becomes:

```
51 + 48 + 57
```

resulting in `156`. Use the [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str2 = "039";
    std::cout << str2[1] << str2[0] << str2[2] << '\n';
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, [character types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) are integral types and your `char` type probably covers the range from `-127` to `127`. This also assumes you are using [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) which maps the characters to values given above.

Comment: Minor nit:  You might point out that the numeric values of the characters is an implementation detail (but the OP is unlikely to be using a machine which *isn't* ASCII - even ignore the fact that the result is what they report).

Answer (score 1):

If str2[1] is char, then:

Char is just like int, but from -127 to 127(or 0 to 255). See ASCII codes.
Then if you do `str2[1]+str2[0]+str2[2]`, you will get some ASCII code.
In c++ you can't do `char+char and get 2 chars`.
Do this:

```
cout<<str2[1]<<str2[0]<<str2[2]<<endl;
```

Comment: Nit: form->from.  More seriously, char can either by -127 to 127 or 0 to 255 (and in principle, it is allowed to be bigger than eight bits too).  Finally, note that the characters are not guaranteed to be ASCII either (although the OP is probably not using an EBCDIC machine).

Comment: @MartinBonner form-from changed. I know that there is also `unsigned char`, but I just wanted to write that char is storing number.

Comment: My point is that `char` may not be signed.  `signed char` is definitely signed, `unsigned char` is definitely unsigned, it is implementation defined whether `char c` is signed or unsigned.  (And all three are distinct types when it comes to overloading, despite the fact that two of them *must* be identical.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need retrieve result as a string use `ostringstream` :

```
#include <sstream>
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << str2[1] << str2[0]<< str2[2];
std::string res = stream.str();
std::cout <<"> " << res << std::endl;
```